# How to resize input/submit box in Bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a fairly simple large input along with a submit box using the bootstrap3 framework, which is displaying perfectly on desktop/tablet resolutions, but viewed under a mobile viewport the submit button slides under the input box, and it looks rather ugly.

How do I either shrink the input/submit buttons to resize appropriately so they don't tile on top of each other, or alternatively if that's not possible have the submit button center align on mobile screensize only?

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">          
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="../includes/some.php"     method="POST" id="navbar">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="focusedInput" autocomplete="off"  maxlength="17" placeholder="Enter number" name="number">            
      </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="something">SUBMIT</button>             
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/uradA/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="../includes/some.php" method="POST" id="navbar">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="focusedInput" style="width:100%" autocomplete="off" maxlength="17" placeholder="Enter number" name="number"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block submit-btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="something">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this as taken from [Button addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons):

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control big">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary big" type="button">Submit</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `big` is:

```
.big {
  font-size: 30px;  
  height: 80px;
}
```

Here is the updated example: [jsfiddle.net/uradA](http://jsfiddle.net/uradA/10/)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good solution, however when it's viewed on a mobile device the input size isn't large enough, and the 17 chars I need to submit start to wrap within the box. See - http://imgur.com/PhtXUa8 for a screenshot.